# Only last email from file array being loaded

Tags: customer, magento-ce

I'm running into the following problem:
I have a list of emails in a file. I want to loop through these and create customers, then I want to do something with the customer. However in my script it's only loading the last customer.

I have the following code:

```
require_once("./app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();

$file = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
if ($file) {
    $emails = file("Test.txt");
    foreach($emails as $email) {

    echo $email . "<br/>"; // < shows all emails

    // load up the customer 
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(1)
    ->loadByEmail($email);

    echo $customer->getId() . "<br/>"; // < returns blank except for the last email line

    // if we found the customer
    if ($customer->getId()){
        echo $customer->getId() . "adsf<br/>"; // < only shown on last line
        //.. do something
    }
    }

    fclose($file);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

I have also tried

```
while(!feof($file)){
    $email = fgets($file);
```

and

```
while (($email = fgets($file)) !== false)
```

but same result, so it appears it's not something wrong with the php code. Can someone help me?

Comment: have you  check this email is exits in admin

Comment: yes they exist. I tested it also by putting a different email last in the file, then it always takes the last email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should read your file line by line and load the customers.
I've had issues before where text files saved on Windows had unreadable line endings. Make sure it doesn't see all the email addresses as one line

```
if ($file = fopen("Test.txt", "rfile)) {
    while (($email = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $email . "<br/>"; // < shows all emails

        // load up the customer 
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
           ->setWebsiteId(1)
           ->loadByEmail(trim($email));

         echo $customer->getId() . "<br/>"; // < returns blank except for the last email line

         // if we found the customer
         if ($customer->getId()){
            echo $customer->getId() . "adsf<br/>"; // < only shown on last line
            //.. do something
         }
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```